# Why is my bake showing as totally flat?

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I'm trying to bake a simple normal map for a tile texture to use in a game. I've set up the bake exactly as in a tutorial but for some reason the tiles aren't baking properly to the plane and the normal map is coming out flat blue. The image shows the details that aren't being baked on the model.

[image]

File is here: http://filedropper.com/dH2AJHaT

If anyone can help I'd be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't share the file...
But check that the high poly is well selected and the low poly active.

Comment: I've linked the file now. The high poly was selected and the low poly was active when I rendered. I've double and tripe checked and it's still not recognising details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values for `Max Ray Distance` and `Extrusion` are too low :

[image]

`Max Ray Distance` is the maximum length of the rays that Blender shoots from the active object to the highPoly mesh, if it's set too low, the rays won't reach the highPoly mesh and it will get no normal information to write on the file, hence the "flat blue" result you see.

`Extrusion` is used when parts of your lowPoly mesh is "inside" the highPoly one so Blender would inflate your lowPoly mesh by the `Extrude` value. In your case, you don't need it because your plane is above the tiles so there is no need to inflate it anymore.

I got this result by setting `Max Ray Distance` and `Extrusion` to `0` :

[image]

**EDIT**

By the way, a `Max Ray Distance` set to `0` doesn't mean that the ray length will be `0`, it means that there is no limit to `Max Ray Distance` which *basically* means that Blender will shoot the ray and won't stop it until it touches something (I said basically, not litterally :D ).

Comment: It worked! Great explanation, thank you so much!

Comment: Well, I'm glad I helped. Just remember, only use `Max Ray distance` and `Extrude` when you really need them. If your bake works fine without them, just don't use them. There is a Blender Guru tutorial (How to bake perfect normals) that explains the case where you need to use `Max Ray distance`.